# TCP accept and Go concurrency model

Tags: tcp, concurrency, go

Looking at `net.TCPListener`.   One would expect, given the Go concurrency paradigm, for this system functionality to be implemented as a channel, so that you got a `chan *net.Conn` from a `Listen()` function, or something similar to that.

But it seems Accept() is the way, and that just blocks, just like the system accept.  Except it's crippled, because:

- There is no proper select() you can use with it, because go prefers channels
- There is no way to set the blocking options for the server sockets.

So I'm doing something like:

```
    acceptChannel = make(chan *Connection)
    go func() {
      for {
       rw, err := listener.Accept()
       if err != nil { ... handle error ... close(acceptChannel) ... return }
       s.acceptChannel <-&Connection{tcpConn: rw, .... }
      }
    }()
```

Just so that I can use multiple server sockets in a select, or multiplex the wait on Accept() with other channels.  Am I missing something?   I'm new to Go, so I might be overlooking things - but did Go really not implement its own blocking system functions with its own concurrency paradigm?  Do I really need a separate goroutine for every socket (possibly hundreds or thousands) I want to listen with?  Is this the correct idiom to be using, or is there a better way?

Comment: goroutines aren't threads. They are however the proper way to handle concurrent actions in the language, e.g. waiting on Accept from multiple sockets.

Comment: You should maybe watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso and generally try to rethink channels because you don't get their purpose or how to use them to control the flow of your program...  Channels can serve as a blocking mechanism in addition to their primary use which is to pass data into and out of goroutines. Passing connections into channels makes no sense. A more sensible application would be to pass a channel into a method you call in a goroutine, open the connection there and send data back to the caller on the channel. Maybe you have a blocking select there...

Comment: @evanmcdonnal -  Can you show me an example of the approach you suggest?   I don't understand what you are talking about.   I'm trying to multiplex accept() from multiple sockets with other channel recvs.

Comment: Also please see my comment below on @tomasz answer for a clear use case for passing connections on channels.   Whatever you're suggesting has to accomplish the same as that.

Comment: Go isn't Node.js. You can spawn 50k goroutines just fine and blocking I/O is implemented in terms of async I/O.

Comment: For future reference, instead of expressing incredulity about how language X doesn't work the way you think it should; you'll get a better response simply explaining *what* you want to do, and asking *how* to it in language X.

Comment: By "better response" I assume you mean "I won't popularity-contest downvote bomb you".   Or maybe you don't.  I don't know.   In any case I got a proper answer to my (legitimate, site-appropriate) question which is what I wanted.  I'm still incredulous, though.   Accept() as channel is obvious and a huge pain to work around not having, as we've seen here.

Comment: You can actually make `accept` non blocking by using `SetDeadline`. That way `accept` will timeout giving you ability to check for abort condition or something else. Yes, it not an ideal way and you will have to wait for a timeout to occur but it works. I agree with you on that one - `accept` doesn't work very well with everything else in the language and implementing it as a channel would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is just fine. You could even go further and replace:

```
s.acceptChannel <-&Connection{tcpConn: rw, .... }
```

with:

```
go handleConnection(&Connection{tcpConn: rw, .... })
```

As mentioned in the comments, routines are not system threads, they are lightweight threads managed by Go runtime. When you create a routine for every connection, you can easily use blocking operations, which are easier to implement. Go runtime is then *selecting* the routines for you, so the behaviour you're looking for is simply somewhere else, buried into the language. You can't see it, but it's everywhere.

Now, if you need something more sophisticated and, per our conversation, implement something similar to select with a timeout, you would do exactly what you're suggesting: push all the new connection to a channel and multiplex it with a timer. This seems the way to go in Go.

Take a note you can't close the accept channel if *one* of you acceptors fails as another one would panic while writing to it.

My (fuller) example:

```
newConns := make(chan net.Conn)

// For every listener spawn the following routine
go func(l net.Listener) {
    for {
        c, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error (and then for example indicate acceptor is down)
            newConns <- nil
            return
        }
        newConns <- c
    }
}(listener)

for {
    select {
    case c := <-newConns:
        // new connection or nil if acceptor is down, in which case we should
        // do something (respawn, stop when everyone is down or just explode)
    case <-time.After(time.Minute):
        // timeout branch, no connection for a minute
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal of this is not to spawn a connection for each connection here.  That will of course happen, just like it would in any accept/handle net server with a concurrent model in any language.  The goal is to be able to treat all blocking operations consistently.   For example, I might want to be able to multiplex accept() in with a timer goroutine that signals with a channel - if an accept in any of these N server sockets has not happened in timeMillis seconds, execute this code...

Comment: That's simply not possible with using Accept() the way it is, or with spawning off a handler immediately on accept as you suggest.  With traditional concurrency you'd use the "normal" kind of select() on the socket fds with a timed wait.  But that's not available in Go, because channels are favored.  So I'm trying to wrap the accept() in a channel. Make sense?

Comment: @BadZen The way to do that is in a select after the go routine. You use a timer and send on a channel when it expires. In select you call your method in the case that receives on the channel. So no matter what after some Duration d you will send on channel 'doCleanUp' and that will call your method 'doCleanUp' which could for example kill all your go routines and write some status to disk then exit. If I have time today I'll code up some contrived example but basically you should select in the async method and after you invoke it. In both cases you need an exit/abort channel you listen/send on

Comment: Yes, I understand how to multiplex a timer channel with a single "join point" in a goroutine.   Listen to what I'm saying:  "if an accept in *any of these N server sockets* has not happened in timeMillis seconds, execute <default branch code>"   The N server sockets correspond to N instances of the goroutine in my code.

Comment: If you really are proposing something that will execute some code any time a select has not happened in any of those goroutines for a (shared among all, reset-on-any-single-select) interval of time, I apologize for not understanding, but I'm not seeing what you are suggesting.

Comment: @BadZen: you don't have a traditional select, but your example is still easily doable. You can have a timer and every acceptor can call `timer.Reset` to prevent calling the "default branch" etc. Or you can send all the accepted sockets into one channel and multiplex with the timer, as per your example. That's fine and easy to implement. You don't want the accept to be called when the default branch is being executed? Add a mutex or use yet another channel. And so on and so on. You just need to do this differently than with traditional select. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, sure, yeah - I'm not saying your answer doesn't address my use case (didn't think of the "spawn and reset timer /w mutex" option, though that seems less clean to me) - I was addressing @evanmcdonnal in the last two comments.   Sorry, should've tagged.  Was really just looking for "is what I wrote here sane relative to Go, or is there a Better Way"...

Comment: No worries, no misunderstanding here, I was simply addressing your problem. The mutex idea wasn't particularly good anyway – your code sample is basically solving the problem: you're sending all the events from acceptor to one routine, which is multiplexing this channel with a timer, calling some default branch on timeout (acceptors are then blocked, no need to mutex anything, sorry for the crazy idea). So yes, basically you can't do a traditional select and your sample code seem the most idiomatic for me. And I really think is easily readable.

Comment: @BadZen, I've added a fuller example, it might be similar to what you already have, but it will make my response clearer.

Comment: Awesome.  Yeah, that's what I was intending (only with multiple select channels, possibly constructed reflectively, so ack messy left it out) but I should've included in the original.

Comment: Calling this answered, since at least one person wasn't like "OMG you're doing it wrong", and no better suggestions...

Comment: Actually one thing:   any real problem (philosophical or pragmatic) with defer/recover in the accept goroutines to deal with the closing-channel panic you point out?  ( If the listener is closed, I'd expect the pending Accept() to exit, but then there's still a race condition from listener close to accept channel close...)

Comment: My example was more for multiple listeners with one acceptor routine each, so one accept failure wouldn't indicate the failure in another. Are you suggesting multiple acceptors for a single listener? This wouldn't be very useful in this use case I think, one is enough. Anyway, regarding recovering, I don't think it's a nice solution when you know it might happen due to a race condition and you would implement it for a very specific use case (e.g. one and only one listener). There's no reason to if you can easily do it the right way.

Comment: Yeah, 1:1 listener acceptor, of course.   I was just thinking that maybe you could avoid the panic by closing the Listener (causing Accept() to unblock)  before closing the channel.  There's no race condition, disregard that - my bad.  The acceptor goroutines would error-exit on listener close and not try to write.   I think this all works now, TYVM.