# How to suspend and resume accepting new connections in `net.Listener`?

Tags: go, goroutine

Normally, you accept connections in Go like this:

```golang
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

for {
    conn, err := l.Accept() // BLOCKING HERE
    ...
}
```

I want a way to pause and resume the `for` loop depending on user input. Closest I've found is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948954) where accepting happens in a separate goroutine and then `conn` is passed over a channel.

However I don't know how to force that goroutine to exit upon suspension, I don't want to keep accepting new connections when user suspends operations.

Comment: You can’t temporarily break out of `Accept` if that’s what you’re asking. You could easily block _after_ `Accept` returns as long as you want.

Comment: have you tried using context with cancellation ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I got I put together a small example to show how I would have done it. First, let me share the code, then I'll walk you through all the relevant parts.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func handleConnection(ch chan<- string, c net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Serving", c.RemoteAddr().String())
    for {
        netData, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("handleConnection err", err)
            return
        }
        tmp := strings.TrimSpace(string(netData))
        ch <- tmp
        if tmp == "STOP" {
            close(ch)
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("client: %v writes %q\n", c.RemoteAddr().String(), tmp)
    }
    c.Close()
}

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":2000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    go func() {
        for msg := range messages {
            if msg == "STOP" {
                if err := listener.Close(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                os.Exit(0)
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept() // BLOCKING HERE
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go handleConnection(messages, conn)
    }
}
```

Let's start with the easier part which is the function `handleConnection`.

#### The `handleConnection` function

This function accepts a `chan<- string` we use to write messages to and a `net.Conn` that represents a new connection to our listener. To try this out I used telnet connections from my terminal. What this function does is:

- Prints the address of the connected client
- Reads what is written into the connection
- Sends it to the channel
- Checks if the `STOP` word has been written and eventually returns from the function

#### The `main` function

This function does a couple of things worth mentioning:

- Sets the `net.Listener` up on port `2000`
- Runs as a separate goroutine an anonymous function to range over the `messages` channel
- If `STOP` has been received, then it closes the `net.Listener` and exits from the function
- Calls the `Accept` method to listen to incoming TCP client connections
- When a new connection has been received, it spawns a new goroutine to handle it with the above explained function

I hope this clarifies a little bit your question. If I didn't cover something, just let me know and I'll be happy to update my answer, thanks!